# Pandasでquery実行の際に name 'yr' is not definedというエラー

Tags: python, pandas

以下のコードのような`yr`（年）に関するloopを回して、クエリから一部データを抽出し、加工したいのですが、 `name 'yr' is not defined` というエラーが出て実行してくれません。

クエリの中で変数を使うときには、下のような表記ではいけないのでしょうか？
正しい表記法を教えて頂けますと幸いです。

```
for yr in range(2004,2010):
    TF=TS.query('m>(yr+1)*12+0 and m<(yr+1)*12+10')[['CID','m']]
　　…
```

```
[TS]（テストデータ）
ID  m
A   201001
C   200510
E   200601
```

Comment: TSは何でしょうか。pandasのデータフレームですか？

Comment: ローカル変数をクエリ式に含める場合には頭に `@` を付けます。`TS.query('m>(@yr+1)*12+0 and m<(@yr+1)*12+10' )` ただ、クエリ式内で演算が可能であるかどうか不明ですのでエラーになるかもしれません。その場合はクエリ式の外側で予め計算しておく必要があります。

Comment: kcrtさん、データフレームです。状況説明がわかりづらくて申し訳ありません…
metropolisさん、どうやらその表式で良さそうです。大変助かりました！

Answer (score 1):

一応コメント欄で解決したと思いますが、後から見る人の参考になるように…

Pandasのデータフレームの`query`構文の中で、ローカル変数を参照するには、
`変数名`の代わりに`@変数名`を使う必要があります。

たとえば、今回の質問であれば`@yr`とすることで参照することができます。

詳しくは、
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
をご参照ください。

Comment: kcrtさん、ありがとうございます！